# Regex: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'

Tags: python, regex, parsing, logging

I'm quite new to regex.

I have an application log in a dataframe, AppEvents, which I try to split into smaller parts:

```
"[01/30/2018 15:01:24] [Visma.Workflow.Server.exe] Off 

                        [CompanyDatabaseUpgrader.CheckAndUpgradeCompanyDb::0] ThreadId: 12 ThreadName:  

                        Initializing of ERP client complete.    Logged from: CompanyDatabaseUpgrader.CheckAndUpgradeCompanyDb (0)



                         "
```

**Desired output**:

```
[01/30/2018 15:01:24], 
[App.Workflow.Server.exe] Off, [CompanyDatabaseUpgrader.CheckAndUpgradeCompanyDb::0], 
ThreadId: 12, 
ThreadName: Initializing of ERP client complete., 
Logged from: CompanyDatabaseUpgrader.CheckAndUpgradeCompanyDb (0),
```

What I have attempted:

```
regex = re.compile('(.+?)\[(.+?\])] [ThreadID$ \d+] [ThreadName$
+d+]')
    res = regex.match(AppEvents.ix[2,4])
    log_parts = list(res.group())
    App_info = log_parts.pop(-1)
    App_parts = App_info.split(' ')
    log_parts.extend(App_parts)
```

I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group' and I do not know why. Any help appreciated!

Comment: The `regex.match()` is returning `None`

Comment: `ThreadID$` `$` should be escaped you're creating character classes wrongly with `[ThreadID]`

Comment: @mshsayem I did get the error to go away with checking whether the match returned None. However, it does not split anything since it does not find any matches. I tried to rewrite it to regex = re.compile('(.*?)\[(.*?\])] [ThreadID$ \d+] [ThreadName$ \d+]') but to no avail.

Comment: Maybe [http://rextester.com/DRUL38783](http://rextester.com/DRUL38783)

Comment: I would also say your Regex is incorrect. My try: https://regex101.com/r/WEsVKe/1